# Sort cell array based on a column with NaNs

Tags: matlab, sorting

My data is a 1x7 cell called PM25. Inside each cell, there another cell with of size 365x5xN where N varies. Below is part of PM25{1,1} (The data can be found here: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/li3hh1nvt11vok5/4YGfwStQlo. Variable in question is PM25)

```
'42.493056'    '-92.343889'    '19-013-0008'    [733043]    [ NaN]
'42.493056'    '-92.343889'    '19-013-0008'    [733044]    [ NaN]
'42.493056'    '-92.343889'    '19-013-0008'    [733045]    '3.6' 
'42.493056'    '-92.343889'    '19-013-0008'    [733046]    [ NaN]
'42.493056'    '-92.343889'    '19-013-0008'    [733047]    [ NaN]
'42.493056'    '-92.343889'    '19-013-0008'    [733048]    '10'  
'42.493056'    '-92.343889'    '19-013-0008'    [733049]    [ NaN]
'42.493056'    '-92.343889'    '19-013-0008'    [733050]    [ NaN]
'42.493056'    '-92.343889'    '19-013-0008'    [733051]    '5.8' 
'42.493056'    '-92.343889'    '19-013-0008'    [733052]    [ NaN]
'42.493056'    '-92.343889'    '19-013-0008'    [733053]    [ NaN]
'42.493056'    '-92.343889'    '19-013-0008'    [733054]    '7.7'
```

I am trying to sort the whole cell by the last column, the concentration. Here's what I've been doing:

```
% Sort each site based on the concentration values - Descending order with NaN's at the bottom
for i = 1:length(names_PM25_O3) % States
    for j = 1:length(PM25{i}(1,1,:)) % Number of sites
        [~,ix] = sort(str2double(PM25{i}(:,5,j))); % Sorted indices
        nanmask = isnan(str2double(PM25{i}(ix,5,j))); % Get mask (0 or 1) of nan-rows to be ignored
        ix = flipdim(ix(~nanmask),1); % Get non-nan indices in reverse order
        PM25_sorted{i} = PM25{i}(ix,:,:); % Sort
    end
end
```

The thing is that this code only sorts the last N in each of the 7 cells in PM25. All the other N's are sorted according to the last N, and I end up with less than 365 values, possibly because the NaN's are deleted in the last N.

For example, here would be part of N = 1 (PM25{1,1}(:,:,1))

```
'42.493056'    '-92.343889'    '19-013-0008'    [733396]    '63'  
'42.493056'    '-92.343889'    '19-013-0008'    [733393]    '37.5'
'42.493056'    '-92.343889'    '19-013-0008'    [733108]    '28.7'
'42.493056'    '-92.343889'    '19-013-0008'    [733207]    '23.1'
'42.493056'    '-92.343889'    '19-013-0008'    [733366]    '27.7'
'42.493056'    '-92.343889'    '19-013-0008'    [733255]    '19.2'
'42.493056'    '-92.343889'    '19-013-0008'    [733063]    '24.7'
'42.493056'    '-92.343889'    '19-013-0008'    [733225]    '11.7'
'42.493056'    '-92.343889'    '19-013-0008'    [733066]    '19.9'
'42.493056'    '-92.343889'    '19-013-0008'    [733250]    [ NaN]
'42.493056'    '-92.343889'    '19-013-0008'    [733387]    '26.5'
'42.493056'    '-92.343889'    '19-013-0008'    [733153]    '15.6'
'42.493056'    '-92.343889'    '19-013-0008'    [733384]    '12.9'
```

While this would be part of the last N, N = 21 in PM25{1,1}(:,:,21)

```
'42.695391'    '-93.655976'    '19-197-0004'    [733396]    '48'  
'42.695391'    '-93.655976'    '19-197-0004'    [733393]    '36.4'
'42.695391'    '-93.655976'    '19-197-0004'    [733108]    '33.3'
'42.695391'    '-93.655976'    '19-197-0004'    [733207]    '25.4'
'42.695391'    '-93.655976'    '19-197-0004'    [733366]    '24.3'
'42.695391'    '-93.655976'    '19-197-0004'    [733255]    '22.4'
'42.695391'    '-93.655976'    '19-197-0004'    [733063]    '21'  
'42.695391'    '-93.655976'    '19-197-0004'    [733225]    '20'  
'42.695391'    '-93.655976'    '19-197-0004'    [733066]    '19.8'
'42.695391'    '-93.655976'    '19-197-0004'    [733250]    '19.6'
'42.695391'    '-93.655976'    '19-197-0004'    [733387]    '19.5'
'42.695391'    '-93.655976'    '19-197-0004'    [733153]    '19.2'
'42.695391'    '-93.655976'    '19-197-0004'    [733384]    '18.8'
```

As you can see, the N = 21 is sorted in descending order and all the NaN's are gone. But N = 1 is simply in the order that N = 21 is in (look at column 4, the dates - it's in the same order), so it's not sorted in descending order.

How can I get it so the whole cell sorts individually? I will probably have to keep the NaN rows since otherwise, every single N will be a different length. It currently looks like they are being deleted from the sorted N.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function -

```
function sorted_cell_array = sortcell_col5(org_cell_array)

col5 = org_cell_array(:,5);
isnum = cellfun(@isnumeric,col5);
t2 = NaN(size(org_cell_array,1),1);
t2(~isnum) = str2num(char(col5(~isnum)));
[~,y1] = sort(t2);
c1 = nnz(~isnan(t2));
if ~c1
    sorted_cell_array = org_cell_array(y1,:);
else
    ind1 = [ flipud(y1(1:c1)) ; y1(c1+1:end) ];
    sorted_cell_array = org_cell_array(ind1,:);
end

return;
```

Main Script -

```
load data_2007.mat %%// Load your data mat file

PM25_sorted = PM25;
M1 = size(PM25,2);
for k1 = 1:M1
    [sz1,sz2,N] = size(PM25{1,k1});
    for k2 = 1:N
        PM25_sorted{1,k1}(:,:,k2) = sortcell_col5(PM25{1,k1}(:,:,k2));
    end
end
```

Comment: Sort of. The output is what I want, but the cell array I have is not just the example I pasted. It's a few layers deep. You can see it in the link I posted.

Comment: @shizishan You do want the `NaNs` after the numerals right?

Comment: I'll try it (currently can't due to very slow internet and I am running this remotely) with modifications. My cell is in 3D, so it's a bit different.

Comment: @shizishan Edited with few changes and also keep in mind that the current codes would sort in ascending order. For descending order, just add the term 'descend' in the `sort` command.

Comment: One problem: When I sort it descending, all the NaN's are at the top. If I want to pull out the top 36 values, I won't know where the values begin. Is there anyway of sorting descending, but putting the NaN's at the bottom?

Comment: Maybe I can just convert NaN to 0

Comment: @shizishan Fixed, check it out!